# How to user regex to in PowerShell to format a dynamic string to an array?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have this string...

```
12345;#john, doe (io-124)[Company I work for], 8732;#jane, smith (dos-12)[my company], 902743;#jack, johnson (123-as), 1824;#sam, sampson (1235-oi), 089932;#jessie, jackson (1232-ahs)[top notch company], 2134;#last, one (123-fl)
```

I want this output in an array...

```
12345
john, doe (io-124)[Company I work for]
8732
jane, smith (dos-12)[my company]
902743
jack, johnson (123-as)
1824
sam, sampson (1235-oi)
089932
jessie, jackson (1232-ahs)[top notch company]
2134
last, one (123-fl)
```

I'm still learning regex, but managed to find this expression `"\d+;"` That will give me the numbers in the beginning of each substring with a `";"` on the end which I can trim off, but I don't know how to extract that. If I could extract it, I would be left with the names with a `"#"` in the beginning of them. So I could split on those and then trim the spaces off the ends. Even if it put it in 2 arrays would be fine. maybe even better..

Hope this makes sense.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$result = $text -split '(?:,\s*)?(\d+);#?'
# Or, to also remove the empty items:
$result = $text -split '(?:,\s*)?(\d+);#?' | Where-Object {$_}
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3A%2C%5Cs*%29%3F%28%5Cd%2B%29%3B%23%3F&i=12345%3B%23john%2C%20doe%20%28io-124%29%5BCompany%20I%20work%20for%5D%2C%208732%3B%23jane%2C%20smith%20%28dos-12%29%5Bmy%20company%5D%2C%20902743%3B%23jack%2C%20johnson%20%28123-as%29%2C%201824%3B%23sam%2C%20sampson%20%281235-oi%29%2C%20089932%3B%23jessie%2C%20jackson%20%281232-ahs%29%5Btop%20notch%20company%5D%2C%202134%3B%23last%2C%20one%20%28123-fl%29)

The regex matches

- `(?:,\s*)?` - an optional sequence of a comma and then zero or more whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - captures into Group 1 (and thus also outputs these values) one or more digits
- `;#?` - a `;` and an optional `#`.

Comment: This worked perfect!! Thanks a ton! Happy coding!

Comment: A little less verbose: `$result = $text -split '(?:,\s*)?(\d+);#?'`

Comment: @ShaneSmith If my answer does not help you solve the issue, please consider updating the question.

Answer (score 1):

You might use a pattern with 2 capture groups and add the groups to an array

```
(\d+);#(.*?)(?=,\s+\d+;|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `(\d+)` Capture 1+ digits in group 1
- `;#` Match literally
- `(.*?)` Capture group 2, match as least chars as possible (non greedy)
- `(?=` Positive lookahead to assert what is at the right is

  - `,\s+\d+;|$` Match 1+ whitespaces, 1+ digits and `;` or assert the end of the string to also get the last item
- `)` Close the lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7fUmdq/1) and a [Powershell demo](https://tio.run/##dZBRa9swFIXf/SsujaHWapnaSWlCKF0obAy29SGwFzcMzVZqtbKu0ZXJwprfnt3EKfSh1ZOk851zrtThRntqtLX7fUzBww2c5cV4cjUfPWHjUqhRQ2JQ5sVElHfYdspt4Rts0D/DGv0qhen1uGBaOZ0CtSY0kNRIbBBlu4VqsDA3uyyuJ@MDWT2ncEgndJBwm1QkUsinxWQ@ItVyjGq7V/FKomH1cjqbHXs0keGmQ8orUkjVkCgDduAwVM2b0iIfc6hVFFJAp4e6tRVnUez1o/7L7z1PHuoLMR8l2adbkdzepA90wTfzl1icR7EJuiWmyuWWeJvdobW6CgYdZQvv1fa7obD6nIhoqQ@CXAZv3COc4qVxXR/g@LVyYe0PxfNpghf4gl6rqpH3f57YBv/i39lJ3L2jRsBrGCZb1HXC9FePfUdlvsp@Kdtrwa77PsifvbUf08V79C5aD3XJ0QPGncwiGoo3no@yQQqDEO32@/8)

```
$regex = '(\d+);#(.*?)(?=,\s+\d+;|$)'
$items = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
Select-String $regex -input $str -AllMatches | Foreach-Object {$_.Matches} | Foreach-Object {
    $items.Add($_.Groups[1].Value) | Out-Null
    $items.Add($_.Groups[2].Value) | Out-Null
}
```